# JQuery Tooltip effects not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, tooltip

I'm using jquery-1.7.2.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js and wanted to implement a Tooltip. It worked right out of the box, but later I planned to customize some of the default effects and they don't seem to work.

Here's the code:

```
 $(function () {
    var temp = $("#tooltipname").attr('title');
    $("#tooltipname").tooltip({
        content: temp,
        position: "top",
        opacity: 0.1,
        effect: 'fade',
        predelay: 3000,
        fadeInSpeed: 3000,
    });
})
```

the strange thing is that the content attribute works fine and as you can see I assign it a value of temp variable. The value of temp is read from the title value of HTML span tag. Nevertheless the other attributes don't work at all.

---

I've played a bit with my code after getting help from you guys and decided to share the code I made in jsFiddle. I show how to implement not only one tooltip but all tooltips designated by #tooltipname on the whole page. Moreover the code shows how to break lines (multiline tooltip), which was not trivial to achieve.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<span title="my tooltip1 <br> new line" id="tooltipname">Hover me</span>

<span title="my tooltip2 <br> new line" id="tooltipname">Hover me2</span>
```

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var temp = $("#tooltipname").attr('title');
    $(this).tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return $(this).attr("title");
        },
        position: {
            at: "center bottom",
            my: "center top"
        },
        opacity: 0.1,
        show: {
            effect: 'fadeIn',
            duration: 500,
            delay: 500
        },
    });
});
```

Hope it's helpfull for other newcomers to JQuery.

For those of you who'd like to play with this code -> [jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Jack_Harper/3y2az/)

Comment: How about making Fiddle with this?

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/pranshu82202/TVN4c/

Comment: Thanks for that Fiddle code, but it's the same. I can see the tooltip, but can't modify it's behaviour. Just change the predelay or fadeInSpeed times to some big values. They don't work. Changing position to "bottom" also doesn't work.... at least in my case.

Comment: Look my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/w8CEd/

Comment: I can see the following: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12017775/jsFiddle/2014-07-17%2010_21_55-Edit%20fiddle%20-%20JSFiddle.png). Time changes take no effect. Positioning either.

Comment: Ok, so you know what was your problem. Now you can fix it.

Comment: And this applied to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/3w95H/

Comment: My answer is now updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as expected. Your `p` is taking the 100% width of the page, and the tooltip is positioning on the top and center of that. You need to set your '#tooltipname' as 'inline-block' or something like that.

And according to the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position) you need to set the `my` and `at` values.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mneb2/)

Comment: It's much better now at least about positioning, though time settings are still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to add more properties you need to check the documentation. I don't know what `predelay` effect is for, but I added the fadeIn option with your speed value: http://jsfiddle.net/mneb2/

Comment: Great! I read the documentation and sample codes of other people and apparently overlooked something. Your Fiddle example is what I was looking for. Thanks again. Thumbs up!